# Guzzle Sends HTTP request to Google API, server 500 error

Tags: php, gmail-api, guzzle

I use Guzzle to send HTTP request to [Gmail API](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

This part keeps causing a server 500 error, why is that ?

```
$data = new stdClass; 
$data-> 'topicName' ='projects/sample.com:sample/topics/topic';   
$data-> 'labelIds' = ["INBOX"];
$data-> 'labelFilterAction' = 'include';
```

Full code:

```
    require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly");
    putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=sample.json');
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    // returns a Guzzle HTTP Client
    $httpClient = $client->authorize();
    $data = new stdClass; 
    $data->'topicName' ='projects/sample.com:sample/topics/topic';   
    $data-> 'labelIds' = ["INBOX"];
    $data-> 'labelFilterAction' = 'include';
    $request = new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('POST', 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/post@sample.com/watch',['Content-type'=>'application/json'],$data);
    $response = $httpClient->send($request);

    var_dump($response);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have single quotes around you $data object's properties.

It should be:

```
$data->topicName ='projects/sample.com:sample/topics/topic';   
$data->labelIds = ["INBOX"];
$data->labelFilterAction = 'include';
```